# matlab-create a matrix of transfer function

Tags: matlab, transfer-function

How can I define an n-by-n transfer function matrix in matlab? I just need to initialize it since I will load it with the correct tf in a second part of my code.

I tried with the definition:

```
MATRIX=zeros(n);
```

but each element of MATRIX is of double type. I want each element to be of tf data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to create [Model Array](https://se.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/model-arrays.html). The command also depends on the number of inputs and outputs in your system. You can create it using for example:

```
MATRIX = tf(zeros(no_inputs, no_outputs, n, n));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two transfer functions for a S/MIMO system (actually a concatenation of SISO models):

```
s = tf('s')
h11 = (s-1)/(s+1)
h21 = (s+2)/(s^2+4*s+5)
% or
% h11 = tf([1 -1],[1 1])
% h21 = tf([1 2],[1 4 5])
```

they can be concatenated to form H(s).

```
H = [h11; h21]
```

You can also pass directly by `tf` using cell arrays:

```
h11 = {[1 -1];[1 2]}
h21 = {[1 1];[1 4 5]}
H = tf(N,D)
```

Both works also for `zpk` models.